# GridView in ASP.NET is not displaying with or without data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm adding a GridView & then showing data in it from a SQL Server database. The problem is that the GridView is not displaying in the browser with or without data.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridAllStore"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"  ViewStateMode="Enabled">
```

```
public partial class AdminPanel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    storelocatorDataSetTableAdapters.storedbTableAdapter tastore = new storelocatorDataSetTableAdapters.storedbTableAdapter();
    storelocatorDataSetTableAdapters.View_1TableAdapter taview = new storelocatorDataSetTableAdapters.View_1TableAdapter();

    List<storelocatorDataSet.storedbRow> lststore = new List<storelocatorDataSet.storedbRow>();
    List<storelocatorDataSet.View_1Row> lstview = new List<storelocatorDataSet.View_1Row>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstview = taview.GetData().ToList();
        GridAllStore.DataSource = lstview; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to call `GridAllStore.DataBind()`

Comment: You either have to set AutoGenerateColumns to true ot provide the columns as Bound- or TemplateFields that you want to show. You must DataBind irt either way.

Comment: Is that your complete markup for the `GridView`?

Comment: Still data is not displaying . Actually gridview is not displaying in browser from the beginning . I thought adding data source will solve the problem . :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't defined any columns to display. You have to explicitly define the columns when you set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false.

To make sure that the basics are working set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridAllStore"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Width="100%"  ViewStateMode="Enabled">
```

With `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true, the datasource assigned, and `DataBind()` called, you should start seeing some data. Once you start seeing the data, you can define the specific columns you want to display.

Since you only need to bind the grid on the first page load, utilize the `!Page.IsPostBack` condition:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GridAllStore.DataSource = lstview;
        GridAllStore.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstview = taview.GetData().ToList();
    GridAllStore.DataSource = lstview; 
    GridAllStore.DataBind();
}
```

And change your GridView markup to:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridAllStore"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Width="100%"  ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

Noticed that it is now `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` as this will show the data and generate the columns. You might need to customise what is being shown though. To do this, since you dont really know what you are doing just now, switch to the design view and you can edit the gridview template.

Check out this post for some help with customizing the columns and data that you output. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Comment: Thanks ! :) I have just done that . It worked .  But I really don't have any idea how to remove autogenereated columns . Can you help me please ?

Comment: If you open up the .aspx page in design view mode, you can click on the GridView control and edit it. It allows you to select what columns you want to display. Alternatively, you can use custom `TemplateFields`. Maybe have a look here for some help with it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Comment: If you need anymore help with that, give us a yell!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding following line immediately after setting the Datasource ?

```
GridAllStore.DataBind();
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have data in lstview ?

Comment: And AutoGenerateColumns is set to true too ? Also check grid's visibility and it's parent control's visibility. Do a view source too and see if grid is there but not showing up for some reason.

Comment: It worked now after setting the AutogeneratedColumns to true . :D But , now I want to remove the autogeneratedcolumns. How van I do that ?

Comment: You can turn off the property and add your own columns. Here's a tutorial to get you started : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/adding-bound-columns-to-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: I just checked your tuto . It gives me error like this : 
Error Creating Control - GridAllStoreLiteral content ('<asp :BoundField HeaderText="Store" DataField="name" __designer:mapid="81" /> <asp :BoundField HeaderText="Contact No." DataField="contact" __designer:mapid="82" /> <asp :BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="address" __designer:mapid="83" />') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.

Comment: Not sure you are implementing, you would need to share the exact grid code. I would suggest you to open a new question for that.